# How to get bootstrap to work with EE

Tags: bootstrap

I'm making responsive website based on bootstrap front-end framework, but when I "move" static and working HTML pages to EE templates bootstrap parts are not working (for an example accordion effect). Bootstrap CSS and JS are included in the header.

Any particular steps must be taken to get this to work with EE?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, way to vague here. What's not working exactly? What errors are you seeing? Any console errors? Please revise your question with more detail, and code examples if possible.

Comment: You probably need to adjust the paths to your css and javascripts

Comment: OP updated. Paths to CSS and JS are proper (can open from view source).

Comment: And errors in the console?

Comment: I have worked with Boostrap in EE seam free. Have you triple checked that all the required JS, CSS and HTML is in the templates?

Comment: Can you provide a link? I've built several sites using bootstrap without an error. I still feel like it's your path settings.

Comment: Well guys, mea culpa - I have used LESS version of Bootstrap :\

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because ExpressionEngine's front end is a blank canvas - if a particular front end framework is not working then it cannot possibly be the fault of EE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to use up to date and plain Bootstrap, no LESS version or use Eeless http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/eeless